# Why isn't my promise getting resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have two functions - A helper function for downloading files which is as follows

```
var downloadHelper = function(url, saveDir) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("success");    
    }, 2000);


    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now I have a list of files to be downloaded in parallel. I have the logic for that function as follows:

```
var downloadAll = function() {
    var fileDownloadList = []
    for(var key in config.files) {

        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var saveLocation = __base + config.localDir
        downloadHelper(
            config.files[key], 
            saveLocation
        ).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve("downloaded: " + fileUrl);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        fileDownloadList.push(deferred.promise);
    }

    Q.all(fileDownloadList).done(function() {
        console.log("All downloaded");
    },function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(fileDownloadList);
    }, 10000);
}
```

The done is never getting called!

For debugging purposes, I added a setTimeout that will be called after 10 seconds and what I see is that out of 2 files, the second promise is resolved and the first one is still in pending state.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're badly misusing promises. You should be pushing the one returned from `downloadHelper` directly into your array, not needlessly wrapping promises in promises in promises.

Comment: your deferred object in downloadAll gets overwritten in each iteration of the for loop. So, only the last will ever get resolved

Comment: @JaromandaX But aren't I creating a new deferred object with `var deferred = Q.defer()` ?

Comment: yes, but the deferred in `.then` is the last one created - because asynchrony

Comment: Are you sure about that @JaromandaX ? I feel pretty confident that the promise gets created, gets pushed to the fileDownloadList Array, and then  the next one does the same thing. Both can still get resolved.

"because asynchrony" -- no, it's the one that it was when the function in the .then() was created, because of closure.

Comment: Let's refer to the question - which promise gets resolved - `out of two, the second one is resolved` ... if there were three promises, I bet the 3rd would be the one that is resolved

Comment: @TKoL The `then` handlers enclose the `deferred` variable.

Comment: if you were to wrap the code inside the for loop in a closure, the code would work as expected

Comment: @TKoL "because of closure" - what closure?

Comment: @JaromandaX  , yes, I see now, there is only one 'deferred' variable being enclosed and it gets overwritten every time through the loop. I forgot about this problem wtih javascript looping because I've been using array.forEach() for a while now, which avoids that problem.

Comment: @TKoL yes, that's one of the benefits of `array#forEach` and family :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make your code work

```
for(var key in config.files) {
    (function() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var saveLocation = __base + config.localDir
        downloadHelper(
            config.files[key], 
            saveLocation
        ).then(function() {
            deferred.resolve("downloaded: " + fileUrl);
        }).catch(function(err) {
           deferred.reject(err);
        });
        fileDownloadList.push(deferred.promise);
    }());
}
```

But since downloadhelper returns a promise, no need to create yet another one

```
for (var key in config.files) {
    var saveLocation = __base + config.localDir
    fileDownloadList.push(downloadHelper(
        config.files[key],
        saveLocation
    ).then(function () {
        return("downloaded: " + fileUrl);
    }));
}
```

You'll see I removed

```
.catch(function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
})
```

That's redundant, it's the same as not having the catch at all